# Service 'myservice' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk --update --no-cache

Tags: php, windows, docker, docker-compose

I'm working on a project on windows 10 with Docker version 2.3.0.3 (45519) - engine 19.03.8 - Compose 1.25.5, and I'm getting the following issue when trying to buid images and run containers with `docker-compose up -d`:

```
Step 10/20 : RUN apk --update --no-cache --virtual add .build-deps     $PHPIZE_DEPS     g++     git     icu-dev     libxml2-dev     postgresql-dev     zip
 zlib-dev
 ---> Running in 207375af7c4c
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz: could not connect to server (check repositories file)
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz: could not connect to server (check repositories file)
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  add-0:
    masked in: cache
    satisfies: world[add]
  .build-deps (missing):
    required by:
  autoconf (missing):
    required by:
  dpkg-dev (missing):
    required by:
  dpkg (missing):
    required by:
  file (missing):
    required by:
  g++ (missing):
    required by:
  gcc (missing):
    required by:
  libc-dev (missing):
    required by:
  make (missing):
    required by:
  pkgconf (missing):
    required by:
  re2c (missing):
    required by:
  git (missing):
    required by:
  icu-dev (missing):
    required by:
  libxml2-dev (missing):
    required by:
  postgresql-dev (missing):
    required by:
  zip (missing):
    required by:
  zlib-dev (missing):
    required by:
ERROR: Service 'myservice' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk --update --no-cache --virtual add .build-deps     $PHPIZE_DEPS     g++     git     icu-dev     libxml2-dev     postgresql-dev     zip     zlib-dev' returned a non-zero code: 18
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine3.8 as myserviceimage



USER root

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

ADD . /app

WORKDIR /app/app

RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    g++ \
    git \
    icu-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    #nginx \
    postgresql-dev \
    zip \
    zlib-dev

# install php-ext
RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl --enable-intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl pdo_pgsql xml hash zip pgsql

RUN pecl install mongodb
RUN docker-php-ext-enable mongodb

# Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 8001



CMD ["php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:8001", "web/app_dev.php"]
```

And the docker-compose.yml file is:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  aphpqmbe:
    container_name: myservicecontainer
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile

    environment:
      CONSUMER_HOST: 'localhost'
      PCONSUMER_PORT: 5432
      PCONSUMER_NAME: 'consumer'
      CONSUMER_USER: 'postgres'
      CONSUMER_PASSWORD: 'root'
      
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
    volumes:
      - './:app/app:rw'
      - './docker/php/conf/dev/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini'
      # - './docker/php/conf/production/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini' -> Used for production


    restart: always

  nginx:
    container_name: container_nginx
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./DockerfileNginx
    links:
      - myservice
    volumes:
      - './:app/app:rw'
      - './docker/nginx/conf/core/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'
      - './docker/nginx/conf/dev/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf'
      # - './docker/nginx/conf/production/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' -> Uncommented this line for production.
      - './docker/nginx/logs/:/var/log/nginx'

    restart: always

  postgresql:
    container_name: consumer_postgresql
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: 'consumer-db'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'root'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - './docker/pgsql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw'
    restart: always

  mongodb:
    container_name: consumer_mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: 'mongo-consumer'
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: 'root'
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - './docker/mongo/data:/data/db'
    restart: always
```

Any hints about anything that might be wrong in my code ?

UPDATE:
If that can help, I have wamp installed in my local machine

Comment: looks like the upstream mirror is down.Try again later

Comment: I've tried over and other for about 4 days now. Could you please explain what is upstream mirror, since I'm a new user of Docker?